# What are the way we can do single binding in Angularjs 1X?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, model-binding

So we do not want to attach the model to scope, No watcher should be created at the backend. Is that possible in Angular 1X?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one-time binding using `::`. Like this:

```
// HTML
{{::someVar}}
```